# Can python classmethod change value of an instance variable and vice versa?

Tags: python

Can python classmethod change value of an instance variable?

And can normal methods change value of the class variable?

Comment: It can if it has access to any instances, i.e. as a parameter or a global variable. And yes, normal methods can modify class variables always.

Answer (score 4):

Any function in python can change any variable it has access to.

---

But that's a broad answer. Let's examine both of your questions in turn:

> Can a class method change the value of an instance variable?

Consider the following class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = 2
        self.prop2 = "Beaver"

    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
        ...
```

If we're inside `do_something`, we don't know whether any specific instances exist. If you were to pass an instance of `A` into the method via an argument, then we could do whatever we wanted to that instance, but unless the instances of `A` are stored somewhere we can see, you can't modify them from within.

One workaround to this is keeping a list of instances in a class variable:

```
class A2:
    instances = []

    def __init__(self):
        # setting instance variables
        self.prop1 = 2
        self.prop2 = "Beaver"
        # setting class variables
        A2.instances.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
        ...
```

This time, we would be able to access an instance from within `do_something`, because that instance would be somewhere in `instances`, which is a class variable.

> Can instance methods change the value of class variables?

Yes, because any instance method is necessarily going to have access to the class of the instance. You can write this explicitly, as we did above in class `A2`, or if you were dealing with polymorphism you could access the `__class__` attribute of the instance:

```
class B(A2):
    def __init__():
        self.prop1 = 7
        self.prop2 = "Chihuaua"
        self.__class__.instances.append(self)
```

---

The principle "you can change anything you can see" is fun and dangerous to mess around with. For example, you can redefine built-in methods, and you can even change class methods from outside of them (here, I will redefine the `__init__()` method of the class `B` outside of the class itself - now all new instances of `B` will use my constructor instead of the one `B` initially came with):

```
def my_new_init(self):
    self.prop1 = 10
    self.prop2 = "bear"
B.__init__ = my_new_init
```

It's extremely dangerous to go down this rabbit hole unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I know that - If we change the value of class variable from the instance variable using Instance.ClassVaribale=0, then only the class variable value for that instance will change. However, when the same change is done via an instance method, then is the behavior same? That is - does the value change only for that instance variable or all instance variables?

Comment: Test it! The python console is perfect for little experiments like this - set up whatever scenario you're curious about, and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

No and Yes.

A classmethod has no access to the instance object.

While an instance method can access the class object via `self.__class__`.

It's however a bad idea to change a value that's global for a class in an instance method because that's an unexpected side effect.

Class-level attributes are transparently accessible via `self` just like instance-specific ones. So if you need to override a class-level attribute for a specific instance, just assign it in `self`:

```
In [1]: class C(object):
   ...:     ca=1
   ...:     cb=1
   ...:     def inc_ca(self):
   ...:         self.ca+=1
   ...:

In [2]: c=C()

In [4]: c.ca
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: c.ca=2

In [6]: c.ca
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: c.inc_ca()

In [8]: c.ca
Out[8]: 3

In [9]: C.ca
Out[9]: 1
```

Comment: When you do `c.ca=2` you are not changing the class property. You are adding a property to the instance  `c` than shadows the class property.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes, and that's exactly what I advise to do.

Comment: Okay, I seem to have misunderstood your answer.

Comment: I know that - If we change the value of class variable from the instance variable using Instance.ClassVaribale=0, then only the class variable value for that instance will change. However, when the same change is done via an instance method, then is the behavior same? That is - does the value change only for that instance variable or all instance variables?

Comment: @variable same. `self` inside an instance method is the same object as `c`. I updated the example.

Comment: What is the difference between: ClassName.attribute vs self.__class__.attribute?

Comment: @variable Technically, no difference. In reality, though, to do `ClassName.attribute`, you need to know ClassName in advance. `self.__class__` is essentially a way to get `ClassName` from an instance of an object

Answer (score 2):

> Can python classmethod change value of an instance variable?

No. Class object does not have *direct* access to any instance variable.

> can normal methods change value of the class variable?

Yes; but the change will be on it's own view (unless the name is referred by using class explicitly e.g. *by name* or *`self.__class__`*) i.e. it won't change the class variable as seen by the class or any other object. If the class object is referred explictly the class variable will be changed as you can imagine.

Comment: So in the instance method - If I use self.__class__.ClassVariableName then all instances will have the change. Where as if we use the Class.ClassVariableName, then only that instance will be updated?

Comment: @variable No. They both do the same thing. `self.__class__` is a way to refer the class from instance without needing to hardcode the class name.

Comment: Ok what do you mean by both will do the same - will update the class variable for all instance or only that instance please?

Comment: @variable If `Class` in your example is the class object, it will update the class variable and if it's an instance then it will update the instance variable.